# Catch a terminating error from a variables method in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to catch an error that is caused when I call a method. In the try block below the `Set-Acl` cmdlet supports `ErrorAction` and allows me to catch. The method `.AddAccessRule` does not support -`ErrorAction`, but does sometimes fail if a user does not exist. How can I catch this error?

```
 Try{
   $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
   Set-Acl $homeDirectory $acl -ErrorAction Stop -ErrorVariable errvar
 }Catch{
   Log $NewUserLog $errvar
   $Response = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Unable to set security on user Folder. Please set NTFS permisions manually." + $ErrorText, "Error")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The catch block should catch the .NET exception thrown by AddAccessRule.  Since you haven't specified a filtering exception on the catch block it should catch all "catchable" .NET exceptions.  There are a few exceptions that aren't catch IIRC like StackOverflowException.